# How can I call a C# method using jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want a C# code behind to be run every second. After googling, I wrote these codes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function () { start() }, 1000);
        function start() {
                time2 = 5;
                //alert("Hello");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm1.aspx/refresh",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Hello");
                    },
                    failure: function () {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
```

And the code behind is:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void refresh()
    {
         //some code
    }
```

But nothing happens. What's wrong?

UPDATE: I installed Firebug and observed that it is reporting "500 Internal Server Error". What does it mean ?

Comment: And what does `refresh()` do?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, did you uncomment this line in the webservice? //To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.

Comment: use firebug and watch any error in console ??

Comment: Make sure you've added ScriptManager and set EnablePageMethods to true and try directly calling start() method instead of calling it in setInterval method.

Comment: Using a web developer tool like Firefox is very helpful for asynchronous operations like this.  There are similar native tools for Chrome, IE, and even Firefox these days.  An HTTP 500 error is a general error being returned by ASP.NET.  My advice would be to inspect the HTTP Response Body with one of the developer tools I mentioned (firebug can probably do this as well).  Often the response body will provide clues such as a partial or complete stack trace to help you resolve the specific ASP.NET error involved here.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. But i assume you are not calling the JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function () { start() }, 1000);
        function start() {
            alert('hi');
            time2 = 5;
            //alert("Hello");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/refresh",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hello");
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }


        myVar;   //------------------> Call the function
    </script>
```

**just call the function by calling myVar;**